# Move a hollow circle on JButton click

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jbutton, helper

I have to create a program that moves the circle using buttons, it doesn't move. I have tried lots of things but I'm afraid I should have organised the classes differently or I'm missing something. Here is the code that moves the circles without the conditions of overlapping.

`DrawCircle` class:

```
public class DrawCircle extends JComponent {
Graphics e;

 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawOval(30,30,50,50);
        e=g;
    }

int moveSpeed = 10;
public void moveUp() {
    if(e.getClipBounds().getMinY() - moveSpeed >= 0){  // make sure the future location of the circle is within bounds of visual frame
        e.setClip( (int) Math. round(e.getClipBounds().getCenterX()),(int) Math. round( e.getClipBounds().getCenterY() - moveSpeed),(int) Math. round( e.getClipBounds().getX()),
            (int) Math. round(e.getClipBounds().getY() - moveSpeed));
    }
    repaint();
}

public void moveDown()
{
    if(e.getClipBounds().getMaxY() - moveSpeed <= 140){  // make sure the future location of the circle is within bounds of visual frame
        e.setClip((int) Math. round(e.getClipBounds().getCenterX()),(int) Math. round( e.getClipBounds().getCenterY() + moveSpeed) ,(int) Math. round( e.getClipBounds().getX()),
            (int) Math. round(e.getClipBounds().getY() + moveSpeed));
    }
    repaint();
}

public void moveRight ()
{
    e.setClip((int) Math. round(e.getClipBounds().getCenterX()-10) ,(int) Math. round( e.getClipBounds().getCenterY()), 
               (int) Math. round(e.getClipBounds().getX()-10), (int) Math. round(e.getClipBounds().getY())  ) ;
    repaint();
}

public void moveLeft()
{
    e.setClip(  (int) Math. round(e.getClipBounds().getCenterX()+10) ,(int) Math. round( e.getClipBounds().getCenterY()),
                (int) Math. round(e.getClipBounds().getX()+10 ),(int) Math. round( e.getClipBounds().getY()));
    repaint();
}
}
```

`Main` Class:

```
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JButton button1;
    final JButton button2;
    final JButton button3;
    final JButton button4;
    JPanel panel;
    final JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500,200);
    final DrawCircle c=new DrawCircle();
    frame.add(c);


     button1=new JButton(" Right ");
     button2=new JButton(" Left ");
     button3=new JButton(" Up ");
     button4=new JButton(" Down ");
     panel=new JPanel();
     panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     panel.add(button1,BorderLayout.WEST);
     panel.add(button2,BorderLayout.EAST);
     panel.add(button3,BorderLayout.NORTH);
     panel.add(button4,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
     frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.EAST);


    class ListenerClass implements ActionListener {
     public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
     {
         if (e.getSource()==button3)
         {
             c.moveUp();
         }
         else if (e.getSource()==button4)
         {
             c.moveDown();
         }
         else if (e.getSource()==button1)
         {
             c.moveRight();
         }
         else if (e.getSource()==button2)
         {
             c.moveLeft();
         }
    }
}

ListenerClass listen=new ListenerClass();
button1.addActionListener (listen);
button2.addActionListener (listen);
button3.addActionListener (listen);
button4.addActionListener (listen);
}

    }
```

Comment: *Here is the code that moves the circles without the conditions of overlapping.* - so why are you trying to write all the code at once? Your first task is to make sure you can move the circle by clicking on a button. Only then should you worry about other constraints. Maybe the reason the circle doesn't move is because your overlapping logic is wrong. You can't solve a problem unless you know what problem you are attempting to solve. Also, why are you playing with the "clip". Again this is unnecessary. Keep the code simple to get it working first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an old sample program of mine. You just have to adjust it a little. Maybe it will help you

```
public class MainPanel extends JFrame {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    ContentPanel drawPanel = new ContentPanel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();       
    }
    
    public MainPanel() {
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        JButton button1 = new JButton();
            button1.setText("/\\");
            button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 50));
            button1.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                y -= 10;
                drawPanel.repaint();
            });
        add(button1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JButton button2 = new JButton();
            button2.setText("<");
            button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 800));
            button2.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                x -= 10;
                drawPanel.repaint();
            });
        add(button2, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JButton button3 = new JButton();
            button3.setText(">");
            button3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 800));
            button3.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                x += 10;
                drawPanel.repaint();
            });
        add(button3, BorderLayout.EAST);
        JButton button4 = new JButton();
            button4.setText("\\/");
            button4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 50));
            button4.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {
                y += 10;
                drawPanel.repaint();
            });
        add(button4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        
        add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class ContentPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillOval(x, y, 50, 50);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(800, 800);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: The x/y variables should NOT be properties of the frame. They are properties of the panel since they control the location of the circle on the panel. Therefore the `ContentPanel` class should have a method that allows you to change the location of the circle. So maybe you need methods like `setCircleX(...)` and `setCircleY()`. Those methods should then invoke repaint(). The ActionListener code should only be responsible for setting the property, NOT invoking repaint.